# AutoLayout constrain issue in the table view cell

Tags: ios, swift4

Can somebody tell why I am not able to display the options of my table view cell in the given screen even after giving the constrain in Autolayout .

Code -

[enter link description here][1]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1opbr0wsxp2t7fr/dropbox.zip?dl=0

Comment: options are display fine in this demo.

Comment: I am not able to display full description of options in my Xcode 9

Comment: @Kuldeep , see the edited code

Comment: you want to see full option title right?

Comment: @Kuldeep , yes and tell me what's the problem

Comment: Please avoid giving link of project without adding some code and more detail.

Comment: @EmreÖnder , Yes sure !!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the text of all button exceed width of table you can increase it or put them inside a `UIStackView` like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: How you have spaced them equally ?

Comment: delete the constraints and drag them inside the stackView and set it's distribution to fillEqually

Comment: see here https://github.com/ShKhan9/stackkk

Comment: @Sudhir, did you try this solution with long options like **NeverNever**. I am sure this solutions doesn't work with long text options.

Comment: neither of the solution is working , I am able to display first and fourth option but not second and third option fully !!!

Comment: @Sudhir, If you want to display your options fully than you have to set button `numberOfLines` to 0 and `lineBreakMode` to `wordWrapping`.